# How to set the library build order in gradle for android?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a custom android.jar which overrides the default android classes and needs to be build before the default android.jar.

In eclipse I can set the order in the tab of 'Order and Export'。But now I'm using gradle, to achieve this,what should i do?

tried following methods but No luck.

Method 1:

```
 configurations
 {
           provided
 }
 dependencies 
 {  
     provided files('PlatformLibs/android.jar')
 }
 android.libraryVariants.all 
 {
   variant -> variant.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.provided
 }
```

Method 2:

```
dependencies 
{
     compile files('PlatformLibs/android.jar')
}
```

Method 3:

```
dependencies 
{
    classpath fileTree(dir: 'PlatformLibs',includes:     ['android.jar'])  
}
```

Any ideas? Any clarification needed? Thanks in advance!